# Entity Framework 6 define a REALLY optional foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

Say I have two tables:

```
Products
[ProductID] PK
[Weight]
[ProductCode]
```

and

```
KnownProductCodes
[ProductCode] PK
[Description]
```

Now I want my `Product` entity to have a `KnownProductCodeDetails` property. BUT the interesting thing here is that `Products.ProductCode` may contain EITHER product codes that DO exist in the `KnownProductCodes` table, OR the product codes THAT DON'T EXIST in `KnownProductCodes` table.

So, my question is: how do I create such a relationship between the two entities in Entity Framework?

PS. By the way, is it possible for an entity to have a foreign relationship without having a corresponding constraint in the database?

Thanks!

==
Details: EF 6.1.2, Code first

Comment: I know it's not the answer to your question, but if you could add `KnownProductCode` (for the ones that do exist) to your products table it would make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an association wouldn't be a foreign key.

A FK is a *contraint*, it uses an entity's primary key values to restrict the domain of values in the referencing entity. However, you don't want the values `Product.ProductCode` to be constrained, so this field can't be a foreign key by definition. (Nor technically).

A second point is that meaningful primary keys, like `KnownProductCodes.ProductCode`, are nearly always a bad idea, because one day the business may demand to change their values. And changing primary key values is a hassle.

So **the obvious thing here** would be to create a real nullable foreign key to a new primary key field, `KnownProductCodesId`. Then you can get the display value for a product's product code either from this FK (if not null) or `Product.ProductCode`. And modifying `KnownProductCodes.ProductCode` is easy now.

**Another approach** could be to create a "free association". Let this be your classes:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public virtual KnownProductCode KnownProductCode { get; set; }
}

public partial class KnownProductCode
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the mappings you can define an association between them:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<KnownProductCode>().HasKey(k => k.ProductCode);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.KnownProductCode)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductCode);
}
```

But in the database you avoid creating the actual FK. EF will allow that, it only wants associations to point to an entity's primary key, but the association doesn't have to be a hard FK in the database.

(Note however that this takes special measures if you create the database from the model, I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I agree with the first two points.

However, using an additional `Products.KnownProductCode` along with `Products.ProductCode` seems to be senseless to me, as it duplicates the data.

Anyway, is it possible to create an association between two entities in Entity Framework without adding a new column?

Comment: Are we on the same page? I mean a FK `Products.KnownProductCodeId` besides `Products.ProductCode` where either the FK or `ProductCode` have a value. No redundancy, only a slight inconvenience because you'll have to resolve `ProductCode` from two possible sources. But you can encapsulate that in the `Product` class.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that personally I'd prefer [paul's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075750/entity-framework-6-define-a-really-optional-foreign-key/28076805?noredirect=1#comment44530697_28075750), but I tried to answer your question by something else than "don't do this".

Comment: Thanks for your replies. However, I'd really love to know whether there's ABSOLUTELY NO other way to implement such an association, without adding a column?

Comment: With "association" I actually mean an EF navigation property.

Comment: Please see the addition.

Comment: In order for this to work I suspect that I'll also need to populate the `Product.KnownProductCode` property somehow?

Comment: Or this approach still involves creating a KnownProductCode column in the database?

Comment: No, just `Product.ProductCode` and you can do e.g. `context.Products.Include(p => p.KnownProductCode)`.

Comment: I have tried your code now. I think it should work, but another problem appearred:
"Product_KnownProductCode: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Product_KnownProductCode_Target' in relationship 'Product_KnownProductCode'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'."

I guess it's because Product.ProductCode has a [Required] attribute applied (since the value can't be null in the database). Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: That's the problem with "hacking" a tool: there's always a chance it starts rubbing elsewhere. I think the only option is to ditch the `[Required]` attribute and do a custom validation in code.